# How to delete a contact?

Tags: android, contacts, delete-row

I'm working at android 2.1 ContactContract, when I had not set account(for example: gmail account) to android emulator then, new a contact, but could not delete this contact at DB.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    String[] args = new String[] {id};
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", args)
            .build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
             .withSelection(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?", args)
             .build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Contacts.CONTENT_URI)
             .withSelection(Contacts._ID + "=?", args)
             .build());
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deleting the contact from RawContacts will delete the data from Data, Contacts table.

```
ArrayList ops = new ArrayList(); String[] args = new String[] {id}; 
// if id is raw contact id
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(RawContacts._ID + "=?", args) .build()); 
    OR
// if id is contact id
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?", args) .build());
getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Comment: Dear Karan, I had a try ,although this method could delete the contact ,it also have some problems. 
  The contacts' information is saved in the file "contacts2.db" , I searched this db file, the contact is deleted in "contacts" table, but is not deleted at "data" table, can you delete a contact completely?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean fullDeleteContactByRawId(String rawId)
{
    Uri rawUri = RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build();
    String where = RawContacts._ID + " = ?";
    String[] args = new String[]{rawId};

    try
    {
        ContentManager.delete(rawUri, where, args);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

notice:
After full delete ,this contact can not sync

Comment: From where do you get `ContentManager?`

Answer (score 0):

I use this to delete a phone number from an existing contact, but not the contact itself:

```
    ArrayList ops = new ArrayList();
    String[] args = new String[]{
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
        number,
        Integer.toString(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MAIN),
        raw_contact_id
    };
    ops.add(
        ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? AND "
                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "=? AND "
                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + "=? AND "
                + ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?"
                , args)
            .build());

    c.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```