# Remove custom account ACCOUNT_TYPE from contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-account, rawcontacts

I have created a custom account and i have added few contacts to that account. So now i want to remove the account from those contacts. I'm Googling since few weeks but i'm not able to find anything. If anyone knows how to do then please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code solved my problem :)

```
    String selection = ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID+ "=?";
    String selectionargs[] = { String.valueOf(rawContactId) }; //Get rawContactId    

    int deletedRawContacts = context.getContentResolver().delete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
                                .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME)
                                .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, ACCOUNT_TYPE)
                                .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build(),
                                 selection,selectionargs);
    System.out.println("No. of contacts deleted are " + deletedRawContacts);
```

**Refer :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/8692909/3142192

Answer (score 0):

*Note: You should modify `RawContacts`, not `Contacts`.
`Contacts` are simply joined `RawContacts`, and `RawContacts` are created on an account.*

Not sure it's possible, since `RawContacts` need to belong to exactly one account.
You can try looping over those `RawContacts`, and change the values at `account_type` and `account_name` to some other **valid** and **existing** account.

it has a chance of succeeding, but I'm not sure you can count on it for all `Android` versions / devices.

Comment: If i try to delete **RawContacts** then whole contacts is getting deleted :(

Comment: are you trying to delete those RawContacts or change their account? You can easily delete them manually by deleting the accounts in phone's settings > accounts > custom account > remove account.

Comment: I don't want to delete all contacts. I just want to delete few or may be one single contact.

Comment: are you talking about deleting it manually? if so, simply open that contact in your contacts app, click edit > menu > separate. Now you'll get each RawContact in its own Contact, delete the one you don't want, and re-merge the rest.

Comment: I solved my problem. Thanks for your response @marmor